# regular expression in name id or class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have for example:

```
<span id="name1">name1</span>
<span id="name2">name2</span>
<span id="name3">name3</span>
<span id="name4">name4</span>
<span id="name5">name5</span>
```

i must use:

```
$("#name1").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
$("#name2").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

etc

i would like somethings:

```
$("#name  [1-5] ").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

i dont will add class. i would like make this for id and regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use a class. It's easy to add, and is exactly the right use for them in this instance. It will also be fastest.
2. Use a loop:

   for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     $("#name" + i).click(function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     });
   }
3. Use attribute selectors: `$('span[id^="name"]')` That will grab all spans with an id that starts with "name". Just know, this is the slowest option, so I would avoid it if you can.

Comment: thanks, and what if i have for example "name1xxx, name2xxx, name10xxx" etc? i would like use 3 method for this.

Comment: You can do `$('span[id^="name"]').filter('span[id$="xxx"]') to get anything that starts with `name` and ends with `xxx`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [attribute startsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to match IDs (or any attribute values) beginning with something.

```
$("span[id^='name']").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/ZBBwh/)

Comment: thanks, and what if i have for example "name1xxx, name2xxx, name10xxx etc"

Comment: Then there's the `endsWith` selector: `$("span[id$='xxx']")`

Comment: can i merge two selector? ^ and & ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("span").filter(function(){
    return /name[1-5]/.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it possible to use `span` as a selector? You probably need to be more specific by, for example, passing the parents class too: `.parentClass span`.

Answer (score 1):

If those are your only span elements, you could do something like

```
$('span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); }
});
```

or if they are the only elements whose ids start with "name" you could use the jQuery "starts with" selector

```
$('[id ^= "name"]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: thanks, and what if i have for example "name1xxx, name2xxx, name10xxx" etc?

Comment: This will select everything that starts with "name", so those would be selected as well. Is that what you want, or would you need those to not be selected?

Comment: i have auto generated ID, name1xxx, name2xxxyyy, name10xxx, name100xxxyyy etc. i would like know how to do :)

Comment: $('[id ^= "name"]') will select everything with an id that starts with "name", such as name1, name10, name2xxxyy, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could just construct the string you are using for the $-selection in a loop like

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
var sel = '#name'+i;
$(sel).doWhatever();
}
```

Although I still think that somehow selecting them in a jQuery way (something like $('#parentElement').find('span')) or using a class might be the better solution

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are OK, but I actually think that if you *can* add a class, you *should*. That's what classes are for - marking the similar / related elements.

If you have just a couple of IDs/classes, you should user '#id1, #id2, ...' selector

If you have multiple, you have to add the class for the sake of semantical and maintainable code and markup